# Does $f$ have to be a continuous function in the definition for an improper integral of an unbounded function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, improper-integrals, definition

I recently learned the following definition for type 2 improper integrals (unbounded functions):

> Let $a < b$.
>
> Let $f$ be a continuous function on $(a, b]$.
>
> We define the integral of $f$ from $a$ to $b$ as
>
> $$ \int_a^b f(x) \, dx = \lim_{c \to a^+}\left[ \int_c^b f(x) \, dx \right] $$
>
> assuming this limit exists.
>
> The integral is convergent when the limit exists.
>
> The integral is divergent when the limit doesn't exist.

Must $f$ be a continuous function in this definition?

Would it be enough, or equivalent, to claim that $f$ is defined on $(a, b]$ and assume that the integral exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function doesn't have to be continuous. On the other hand, it must be assumed that the restriction of $f$ to each interval $[c,b]$, with $c\in(a,b)$, is integrable.